# Prefix routes with dynamic locale depending on user preferences - symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I’m trying to make the base locale change depending on the user preferences. I know I can change the prefix rules in the config, but I don't know how to them make dynamic.

```
app:
    resource: "../src/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        ?: '' # don't prefix URLs for the default locale
        ‘fr|de|es’: ‘{_locale}’
```

Let’s assume we have Client A and Client B.

Client A

- Base: EN
- Secondary: DE, FR

Client B

- Base: FR
- Secondary: ES

For the base locale I don’t want any prefix, only for secondary locales.

Example for Client A

```
‘en’: ‘’
‘de’: ’/de’
’fr’: ‘/fr’
```

Example for Client B

```
‘fr’: ‘’
‘es’: ‘/es’
```

—

Any clue on how can I achieve this through Symfony? Thanks.